# sql error when trying to find total (sum) using a join

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
  2    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
  3    CONCERTS.TYPEOFCONCERT
  4    SUM (CUSTOMERID) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT,
  5    DISTINCT (TYPEOFCONCERT)
  6    FROM CUSTOMER
  7    INNER JOIN BOOKING
  8    ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  9    INNER JOIN EVENT
 10    ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
 11    INNER JOIN CONCERTS
 12    ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID;
  SUM (CUSTOMERID) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT,
      *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I am getting an error when trying to find the total number of customers attending each type of concert. Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You should specify what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: The error message is caused by the missing comma at the end of the third line (after the name of a column in `SELECT`). After you fix that, you will get various other errors, and once you fix them all, you will get an absurd result. Customer id's must be numbers like 9930239 and 8420380. What do you think you will get from `SUM(CUSTOMERID)`? Note that this will simply add all the Customer ID's! Note also that this is a simple logical thing, it has nothing to do with programming in any language.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you want to `COUNT()` the customers and count the distinct types of concerts.  You also need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERID, c.CUSTOMERNAME, co.TYPEOFCONCERT,
       COUNT(CUSTOMERID) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TYPEOFCONCERT)
FROM CUSTOMER c INNER JOIN
     BOOKING b
     ON b.CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID INNER JOIN
     EVENT e
     ON e.EVENTID = b.EVENTID INNER JOIN
     CONCERTS co
     ON co.CONCERTID = e.CONCERTID
GROUP BY c.CUSTOMERID, c.CUSTOMERNAME, co.TYPEOFCONCERT;
```

EDIT:

For the total number attending each type of concert, you can greatly simplify the query:

```
SELECT co.TYPEOFCONCERT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.CUSTOMERID) as num_different_customers,
       COUNT(*) as num_bookings
FROM BOOKING b INNER JOIN
     EVENT e
     ON e.EVENTID = b.EVENTID INNER JOIN
     CONCERTS co
     ON co.CONCERTID = e.CONCERTID
GROUP BY co.TYPEOFCONCERT;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `Customer` table is not needed, because the customer id is in `BOOKING`.
- It is not clear if you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)` or `COUNT(*)`.  The first counts each customers only once for each type, regardless of the number of concerts they booked.

Comment: i wanted to find how many customers are attending each distinct type of concert.

Comment: @sunnyjassal . . . That was not in your original question.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using `SUM` to find counts. Use `COUNT` instead. Also, use proper `group by` clause when using aggregation. `DISTINCT` is not a function. It returns unique combination of selected columns/expression values. Use aliases to make you queries concise.

> total number of customers attending each type of concert

So, you want type of concert and count of customers in it. If so, try this:

```
select t.TYPEOFCONCERT,
    count(*) as customer_count
from CUSTOMER c
inner join BOOKING b on b.cID = c.cID
inner join EVENT e on e.eID = b.eID
inner join CONCERTS t on t.CONCERTID = e.CONCERTID
group by t.TYPEOFCONCERT;
```